# How to notify OSX app when something on Parse changes

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

From time to time my iOS app pushes some `PFObject` (or change some of its fields) to one table.

Since there are **NO push notifications for OSX** (in Parse SDK), can I somehow inform my OSX app that there were some changes on Parse?

Currently app is polling Parse database every second for changes and that makes heavy requests per sec. (I need very fast response, so 1 second is something like max delay).

Answer (score 1):

**It sounds like you need another way to implement OSX push. There are two main options here:**

### 1. Roll your own.

Set up a push notification server and build out your own service. You can find documentation on that here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

http://mobiforge.com/design-development/programming-apple-push-notification-services

### 2. Use a Service besides Parse.com

There are a great number of services that offer OSX push services, and it sounds like you have an OSX app, so local integration should be easy.  Here are a few well-known ones to get you started:

http://www.urbanairship.com

http://responsys.com/marketing-cloud/products/push-IO

https://www.pushwoosh.com/

https://zeropush.com/documentation/apns